# Обратная CSS анимация

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Cделал анимацию на ховер. Не могу добиться такой же обратной анимации при выходе курсора из блока. Какие есть варианты? Конкретно этот пример — это упращенная часть более сложной анимации для понимания алгорится. Поэтому нужна реализации именно через `animation`.

```css
.view {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.view .mask {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.view:hover .mask {
  animation: swipe 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.view h2 {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

@keyframes swipe {
  0% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="mask">
    <h2>Hover Style</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так

```css
.view {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.view .mask {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.view:hover .mask {
  animation: swipe 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.view:not(:hover) .mask {
  animation: swipe-out 0.5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.view h2 {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

@keyframes swipe {
  0% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes swipe-out {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: -100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="mask">
    <h2>Hover Style</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В итоге - за два с половиной года ответ так и не принят. Автор не отписался о том, нашёл ли он решение. Так как анимация (если не использовать JS) будет запускаться сразу при загрузке страницы, то выход здесь один - использование `transition` вместо `animation`.

```css
.view {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.view .mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px; left: 0;
  height: 200px; width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: top 0.75s cubic-bezier(.84,-0.39,.86,.73);
}
.view:hover .mask {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.view h2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="mask">
    <h2>Hover Style</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как раз неуважение авторов вопросов к людям, которые бесплатно тратят своё время - это и есть то, что останавливает меня каждый раз, когда я вижу сложный вопрос и знаю на него точный ответ. В итоге вместо бесплатной и качественной консультации, в лучшем случае - короткий ответ-тычёк в доку